# Use a Mongo Cursor to build a list with another query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, cursor

I have two mongo collections.

Enrollment:

```
{UserID: String, CourseID: String, EducatorFlag: boolean}
```

Courses

```
{_id: String, courseName: String}
```

I'm attempting to generate a list of courseNames when given a UserID. This requires me to find all courses that a User is enrolled in. The following function returns just the CourseID of each course a user is in.

```
var currentCourses = Enrollment.find(
  { UserId: Meteor.userId(), EducatorFlag: false },
  { fields: { CourseID: 1 });
```

I'm unsure of how to take this cursor, and use each item in it to run another query and build a list from the output. Basically for each CourseID in currentCourses I need to do

```
var result = []
result += Courses.find({_id: CourseID}, {fields: {_id: 0, courseName: 1}});
```

The goal is simply to print all the courses that a user is enrolled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use the cursor directly with a `.forEach()`
2. Use `.fetch()` to transform the cursor into an array of objects and then manipulate that.
3. Get an array of `_id`s of enrollments with `.map()` and directly search the courses with mongo's `$in`

Let's just use the first one for now since it's pretty simple:

```
let courseNames = [];
Enrollment.find(
  { UserId: Meteor.userId(), EducatorFlag: false },
  { fields: { CourseID: 1 }).forEach((e)=>{
    let course = Courses.findOne(e.CourseID, { fields: { courseName: 1 }})
    courseNames.push(course.courseName);
});
```

Note: when selecting `fields` in a query you can't mix exclusions and inclusions.

Getting an array of `_id`s and using that with `$in` is also pretty straightforward:

```
let courseIdArray = Enrollment.find(
  { UserId: Meteor.userId(), EducatorFlag: false },
  { fields: { CourseID: 1 }).map((e)=>{ return e.CourseID });

let courseNames = Courses.find(
  { _id: { $in: courseIdArray }}).map((c)=>{ return c.courseName });
```